# cannot add new host to mac OS X

Tags: macos

I am trying to add new entry to the /etc/hosts in mac os (el Capitan)
how ever when I try to ping this entry , I am getting error of not resolved
there is no nsswitch file
what am I missing?

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
local.datafabric.io localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the man page for the hosts file

```
man hosts
```

the syntax is explained:

```
IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
```

so, if you want to add the name `local.datafabric.io` as an alias for localhost (127.0.0.1), the line should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost local.datafabric.io
```

`man` is your friend.

You will probably also want to flush your dnscache. The correct commands for that are depending on the actual version of MacOS.